# Analyze ranked-choice data

Tags: r, ranking

I'm currently doing research and collecting a ranked-choice data. Basically people choosing their preferences in a topic.
E.g., people ranking their preference on fruits: orange, mango, apple, avocado

The clean data frame looks like this:

```
            Fruits                          Color
1   orange;apple;banana;avocado     blue;yellow;red;green
2   avocado;apple;banana;orange     red;green;blue;yellow
3   apple;banana;orange;avocado     yellow;red;green;blue
4   banana;orange;apple;avocado     green;blue;red;yellow
5   apple;avocado;banana;orange     yellow;blue;green;red
```

The first person put orange as their first preference, then apple, banana, and avocado as the last preference.
and so on

**Scoring:**
1st preference = 4; 2nd preference = 3; 3rd preference = 2; 4th preference = 1

**Desired result**

```
        apple   avocado banana  orange  blue    green   red yellow
    1   3       1       2       4       4       1       2       3
    2   3       4       2       1       2       3       4       1
    3   4       1       3       2       1       2       3       4
    4   2       1       4       3       3       4       2       1
    5   4       3       2       1       3       2       1       4
```

The part that I confused is to figure out how to give score for each column -> turn from semicolon separated string into column with numeric value.
If I can pass this, I can create the desired output dataframe.

I've found `pmr` package, but the documentation only a few. Moreover, that package is too advance. I don't really need that for current state, just need simple scores for each preferences

Please help me at the scoring stage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that works using a few `lapply()` and `vapply()` calls, but will generalize to more columns.

```
library(tibble)
d <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Fruits,                          ~Color,
     "orange;apple;banana;avocado",     "blue;yellow;red;green",
     "avocado;apple;banana;orange",     "red;green;blue;yellow",
     "apple;banana;orange;avocado",     "yellow;red;green;blue",
     "banana;orange;apple;avocado",     "green;blue;red;yellow",
     "apple;avocado;banana;orange",     "yellow;blue;green;red"
)


x <- lapply(unname(d), \(col) {
  l <- col %>% strsplit(";")
  x <- l[[1]] %>% unique() %>% sort()
  out <- lapply(x, \(x) {
    vapply(l, FUN.VALUE = numeric(1), \(vec) which(rev(vec) == x))
  })
  names(out) <- x
  as.data.frame(out)
})

do.call(cbind, x)
```

```
  apple avocado banana orange blue green red yellow
1     3       1      2      4    4     1   2      3
2     3       4      2      1    2     3   4      1
3     4       1      3      2    1     2   3      4
4     2       1      4      3    3     4   2      1
5     4       3      2      1    3     2   1      4
```

Comment: This `vapply` is new to me, thanks for new knowledge. I'll check it and come back soon. Since I'm currently at my home, it will take a while to test this bcoz my laptop not super fast

Comment: I've tested this and it works well with more data. Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a tidyverse solution built on `tidyr::separate_rows()` to break apart the items and `dplyr::n() + 1 - dplyr::row_number()` to get reversed ranks by person and category.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

prefs %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  separate_rows(!id) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    !id,
    names_to = "category",
    values_to = "item"
  ) %>%
  group_by(id, category) %>%
  mutate(rank = n() + 1 - row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(category) %>%  
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = id,
    names_from = item,
    values_from = rank
  )
```

```
# A tibble: 5 × 9
     id  blue yellow   red green orange apple banana avocado
  <int> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1     4      3     2     1      4     3      2       1
2     2     2      1     4     3      1     3      2       4
3     3     1      4     3     2      2     4      3       1
4     4     3      1     2     4      3     2      4       1
5     5     3      4     1     2      1     4      2       3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll test this first. Same as my previous comment, it might be take longer to me to come back since my laptop not that fast.
Oh, and ya, that `yellow` appears twice bcoz of typo lol thanks for mentioning

Comment: Oh sorry I'm not aware that I can edit. I'll put that in mind. Anyway, this works well but since I'm working with 32 columns and more than 100 rows, this way seems not super efficient. But still, thanks for the answer, this helps me to see in the different point of view